# Modal Presentation iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I am presenting a modal and it used to go "under" the status bar pre - iOS 11.

iOS 10:
[image]

iOS 11:
[image]

I would like to get it to display like it did in iOS 10

All I was doing before was the following:

```
let vc = ReferralsViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: have you tried adjusting your status bar settings from the info.plist file? StatusBarStyle? StatusBarAppearance?

Comment: I have never done that before because I haven't needed to.  It is just strange to me that this behavior changes between os versions.  What would you recommend to get this to behave the same across os versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue using Storyboard. In my project the view was no longer being pinned to the superview. It looks like they have changed the top constraint to be of type `Superview.Top.Margin` instead of `Superview.Top`. Though it could just be an individual case for me.

**NOTE**: When I did the drop down mine was still set to `superview`. I just switched to another option and then back to `superview`. I then need to change the constant value from 20 to 0.

**Update**
As to crashoverride777 comment, in order for this to work with iPhoneX you should pin your views to the new safe zones.

As you can see there is a gap at the top (the lighter part of the view).

[image]

So I went on onto the constraint that connects that view to the top of the superview and set the second item from `Superview.Top.Margin` to `Superview.Top`.

Finally change the second item from `Superview.Top.Margin` to `Superview.Top`.

So firstly click the view that should be pinned to the top then go to `Show the size inspector`:

[image]

So at the end it should like the below example:

[image]

Comment: Although this wasn't the correct answer, it was similar.  I had to change my top constraint which was to Superview.top to have a -20 constant.  I think there is probably some kind of margin or something there but my vertical space constraint was how you have yours but this was still happening.  So I ran with the -20 to force it over this invisible margin thing

Comment: This answer should really be updated. Your constraints will not work correctly on iPhoneX like this. The reason is because Apple deprecated Top/Bottom layout guide and replaced it with SafeArea. You should pin your constraints to the SafeArea and not the Superview in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Apple deprecated Top/Bottom layout guide and replaced it with SafeArea. You should pin your constraints to the SafeArea and not the Superview in most cases. The currently accepted answer will most likely cause issues on an iPhoneX because everything is pinned to the superview instead of this SafeArea.

Comment: Very true.  I did have to adjust it again for iPhoneX

Comment: Cool, just thought I add to this question when I came across it today. Happy coding.